# NuGet package "opencvdefault" link error on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, nuget, nuget-package

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.
I installed the NuGet opencvdefault package in my C++ project and after including  and rebuilding the project I have these linker errors:

Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A00091D) "public: void __cdecl cv::UMat::copySize(class cv::UMat const &)" (?copySize@UMat@cv@@$$FQEAAXAEBV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl cv::UMat::UMat(class cv::UMat const &)" (??0UMat@cv@@$$FQEAA@AEBV01@@Z)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl cv::UMat::copySize(class cv::UMat const &)" (?copySize@UMat@cv@@$$FQEAAXAEBV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl cv::UMat::UMat(class cv::UMat const &)" (??0UMat@cv@@$$FQEAA@AEBV01@@Z)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::copySize(class cv::Mat const &)" (?copySize@Mat@cv@@QEAAXAEBV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::Mat(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z)
Error   LNK1120 3 unresolved externals

A NuGet installation is not supposed to configure the correct libraries to link?

Project config:
[image: project config]

NuGet package info:
[image]

Comment: Did you check whether your projects setting "Runtime Library" match the one used in the nuget package? Sometimes you're trying to use "dynamic" libraries in a "static" project.

Comment: @Wum My project is dynamic library and I guess the opencvdefault NuGet is also dynamic, link to this NuGet here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/opencvdefault/3.1.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is set up for platform toolset v141 (Visual Studio 2017). The nuget package is build for platform toolset vc12 and vc14 (Visual Studio 2015 and earlier). Try switching your projects platform toolset to v140.
[C++ Binary Compatibility between Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019)

If this platform toolset is not available you could install the v140 toolchain.

Comment: Yes, you nailed it, I found this one that works: opencv.win.native 320.1.1-vs141 its a pre-release so you need to activate the pre-release check box.